# after OTA10 mx4 update can't adb to device, device unauthorised

Tags: adb

Noticed today several days after OTA10, tried to `adb` to device, got:

```
anton@kitten:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
75HABLLE85KB    unauthorized

anton@kitten:~$ adb shell
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

running 15.10, adb version 1.0.32

I was never presented with a dialog on an Ubuntu device to confirm the connection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo adb shell
```

forgot to be a master.

Comment: and just a thought. techraf please revert the changes to the original post. thank you